# How to display a full-page error in Ember.js using error substates?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, error-handling, url-routing

**I am using Ember.js and ember-cli v2.7.0**.

As stated in the Ember Guide on [Loading and Error Substates](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) one can react to an error that occurs when processing the `beforeModel`, `model`, and/or `afterModel`, hooks by creating an `error` action, e.g.:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {

    error(err, transitionTo) {
      if (err) {
        return this.transitionTo('error');
      }
    }

  }
  ...
}
```

If I place that error action in the **routes/application.js** route I will supposedly be able to react to errors that occur in any of those hooks.

#### My goal...

I would like the default behavior of the application to render a full page error, ideally allowing for child routes to redefine this behaviour as depending on the interaction model, for example allowing a child route to render the error into a flash message region or a modal.

When displaying a full page error, I would prefer to do so without transitioning to a new URL. For example if someone requests: `http://myemberapp.com/some/path` and that path errors (for any reason), I would like the default behavior to be to display either a **404**, **500**, in the main `{{outlet}}` of the application.

#### What I've tried so far...

I have played around wit the `this.transitionTo` and I can effectively move from an error substate to a full page, but it moves my user(s) to a new route. I also don't seem to retain the error context, and passing `err` as the second (`model`) argument to `transitionTo` causes its own errors!

#### Next steps...

Now, it clearly seems like `this.transitionTo` is not what I want if I truly want to display the errors "inline" to the page they occur on, because that will take me to the error page route I have defined (**routes/error.js**), and as far as I can tell it transitions without an implicit error model in the above form. Furthermore, as mentioned above, attempting to pass `err` as the second argument causes errors.

At this point in time, I would be OK with transitioning to a new page as an interim solution, but would need to be able to retain access to the error information when reaching the new route and I don't know how to properly pass the error context from the route an error occurs on through the error action to the new route.

Also, as far as I can tell, there is no guarantee what form the error, `err`, will take within the error action. If you follow the JSONAPI spec you might end up with one form of error (a JSON object) but if you invoke invalid javascript code, e.g. `null.boom` it would appear from my testing that the error is different. How does one account for this? I would like to be able to know--whether the error comes from the client or the server--if I should be trying to render a 404, a 500 page, or something else.

(As a bonus, is there any way to get Ember to throw a 404, or similar, error when a user attempts to navigate to a URL that doesn't exist in the router? [Globbing](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard-globbing-routes) maybe?)

I would also like to know if my assumption that I can have some child route, e.g. **some.child.route** pre-empt the default error handling in favor of say an alert or modal, is correct.

I have spent a fair amount of time over the last few months learning Ember.js but this subject seems to have very little knowledge shared on it.

Finally, are there any good articles or tutorials out there that really dissect the topic of error routing and error handling in Ember.js, particularly in the 2.x release series?

Help?

(Thanks in advance!)

---

#### UPDATE (2016/08/18):

I can assign a `lastError` property to the error route's controller before transitioning to it that allows me to access error information in the controller and the template. Is there a better way? E.g.

```
error(err, transitionTo) {
  let errorController = this.controllerFor("error")
  errorController.set("lastError", err);
  this.transitionTo("error");
},
```

Comment: If you get a solution, do post it here.

Comment: Absolutely! I haven't had a chance to revisit this yet but plan on looking into it soon. If I find a good solution for this (or even a "workable hack") I will be happy to share it!

Comment: You can use `service` and `initializer` to add your error object into that service. Here is an example how to handle global notification with `ember service`. 
http://khoapham.me/blog/global-notification-using-ember-initializer-and-service/

Answer (score 0):

You could set a property on the application controller with error information and then display it using the application template.

```js
    {{#if error}}
      <div class="error">{{error}}</div>
    {{else}}
      {{outlet}}
    {{/if}}
```